# writing to .vimrc breaks pathogen?

Tags: vim, pathogen

I have pathogen set up in my vim installation and various plugins installed.

```
"Call pathogen to set up various plugins
"filetype off
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#incubate()
call pathogen#helptags()
```

When I write my .vimrc in vim, the following command is supposed to reload the file (and it does seem to work).

```
" Source the vimrc file after saving it
if has("autocmd")
  autocmd bufwritepost .vimrc source $MYVIMRC
endif
```

After writing .vimrc, however, pathogen does not reload.

Here is the output of :set rtp? after starting vim:

```
runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/Jellybeans,~/.vim/bundle/TwitVim,~/.vim/bundl
e/badwolf,~/.vim/bundle/calendar,~/.vim/bundle/tagbar,~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline,
~/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized,~/.vim/bundle/vim-colorschemes,~/.vim/bundle/
vizardry,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/s
hare/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
```

and after :w in .vimrc it returns to the default.

```
 runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/
vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
```

I tried adding the following modification to no avail...

```
if has("autocmd")
    autocmd bufwritepost .vimrc source $MYVIMRC
    autocmd bufwritepost .vimrc call pathogen#incubate()
endif
```

I've been looking around and can't seem to find a solution other than just restarting vim every time I modify my .vimrc, which is fairly disruptive.  Any help would be appreciated.

edit:  output of tree -d -L 2...

```
.
├── autoload
└── bundle
    ├── badwolf
    ├── calendar
    ├── color~
    ├── Jellybeans
    ├── tagbar
    ├── TwitVim
    ├── vim-airline
    ├── vim-colorschemes
    ├── vim-colors-solarized
    └── vizardry
```

Comment: Why do you call `pathogen#incubate()`? It gets called by `pathogen#infect()` so there would be no reason to include it. Also I can not replicate this from the code snippets you have posted.

Comment: Also make sure to put your autocmds in groups http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024842/vimrc-file-takes-longer-and-longer-to-reload/18025045#18025045

Comment: I added pathogen#incubate a while ago after being prompted by the program, I believe, and as I was diagnosing the problem I think I tried different combinations of execute pathogen#infect(), call pathogen#infect(), and call pathogen#incubate()...  For a while I just thought pathogen#infect() was broken.  However, it does seem to work, until I write my .vimrc.

Comment: As for autocmd, I will address that, but saving my .vimrc doesn't seem like it should reset the rtp, right?  I can post the whole file up on pastebin.  It's a bit of a hodgepodge as I'm new to vim.  http://pastebin.com/YUU0HyVu

Comment: OK, I did the obvious.  Commenting out `autocmd bufwritepost .vimrc source $MYVIMRC` seems to remove the problem.  I liked that feature though, since I am often discovering new features and modifying .vimrc very frequently, so any help implementing this without breaking pathogen would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be the following lines on your `.vimrc`:

```
" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages available in Debian.
runtime! debian.vim
```

On `$VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim` there is a line that reset the runtime path:

```
" Debian system-wide default configuration Vim

set runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim74,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
```

The problem doesn't happens when the .vimrc is loaded on startup because these lines are executed before `call pathogen#infect()`. When you reload your .vimrc you are overwriting your `&rtp`, but pathogen doesn't set it again (possible because `s:done_bundles` is already set).

Comment: The following code fixes it:   
`if (exists("g:loaded_pathogen")==0)   
  runtime! debian.vim   
endif`

Comment: @thoss `!exists()` is an idiom easier to understand when compared to `exists() == 0`, but of course they achieve the same result.

Comment: Right, I realized that shortly after posting -- I had mistyped the !exists command and thought that syntax didn't work in vim.