# Vim is more and more slow each time I save (:w)

Tags: vim

Vim is more and more slow each time I save (:w) until 10 min after 4 or 5 save.
I use *gvim* on windows.
I find that [How to see which plugins are making Vim slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213597/how-to-see-which-plugins-are-making-vim-slow)
but when I run `:version` , it indicates me **profile** features isn't included. I have clean all plugin to see if problem come from them, but nothing changed.
Please help.

Comment: It takes 10 minutes to save after 4 or 5 saves or it starts to slow down after 10 minutes of use (which happens to be 4 or 5 saves)?  Are you saving to disk or a network location?

Comment: Slow to write to disk, or slow to react when you press a touch ?

Comment: My guess would be you have a stray autocmd that keeps getting resourced. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18025045/1890567

Comment: my _vimrc https://gist.github.com/codeur4/fba59ef300fe15fb8e34

Comment: I found the solution !!

I delete this line in my vimrc file :
`autocmd BufWritePost .vimrc,_vimrc source $MYVIMRC`

ty for all your advice

Comment: I indicated why it is different from the other question : I don't have profil so the related answer won't help me